# Angular 2 Array.map returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm stuck with return a value using Array.map in Angular 2
So what am I missing here?

```
export class TabsPage {
    @ViewChild(SuperTabs) superTabs: SuperTabs;

    public rootTab: string = 'ProductListPage';
    public categories: Array<any>;
    public collection_id: number;
    public selectedindex: any;

    private getArrayIndex(source, target) {
        source.map((element, index) => {
            if (element.attrs.collection_id === target) {
                // Returns the Value i need
                console.log('i: ', index);
                return index;
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        public shopifyClientProvider: ShopifyClientProvider,
        private superTabsCtrl: SuperTabsController,
    ) {
        this.categories = navParams.get('collections');
        this.collection_id = navParams.get('collection_id');
        this.selectedindex = this.getArrayIndex(this.categories, navParams.get('collection_id'));

        // Returns undefined
        console.log('Index ', this.selectedindex);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes because you are checking condition with  `element.attrs.collection_id === target` and inside of if you returning some index. If condition is not matched by default it will undefined return. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Instead of that use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: But then the console.log should also return undefined. And even if i define this "return 1", the result is "undefined"

Comment: if your condition not matched then it will not go inside of `if`  you can try with `debugger`.

Comment: No, that is not the Problem. Checked that with Debugger. And the Condition is fullfilled. It seems that Typescript breaks the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to do this in pretty short order:

I don't know exactly what your data looks like, but given an array:

```
const target = 2;
const source = [
  {
    attrs: {
      collection_id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    attrs: {
      collection_id: 2
    }
  },
  {
    attrs: {
      collection_id: 3
    }
  },
];

const index = source.findIndex(element => element.attrs.collection_id === target);
```

would return `1` for the index. If the index isn't found, `-1` will be returned.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5B0gnREzyz6IJ3W3

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Thanks for this Solution. It works for me

Comment: Super! Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is already answered but I have one solution for this same.

> .ts file code

```
 private getArrayIndex(source, target) {
  let indx = -1;
  source.map((element, index) => {
    if (element.attrs.collection_id === target) {
      // Returns the Value i need
      console.log('i: ', index);
      indx = index;
    }
  });
  return indx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Typescript breaks the return. With this modification i get the desired Value:

```
private getArrayIndex(source, target) {
    let found: number;
    source.map((element, index) => {
        if (element.attrs.collection_id === target) {
            console.log('i: ', index);
            found = index;
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```